Round robin schedule with four men and four women, need three rounds gender doubles and four rounds mixed doubles
I have four men (1, 2, 3, 4) and four women (5, 6, 7, 8), playing in teams of two across seven rounds.  Each round consists of two games with teams of two playing each other, and all players play in each round.
I want three rounds of gender doubles (so that each possible team of men, and of women, play together).  That part is straightforward.
Then I'd like four rounds of mixed doubles, where each team has one man and one woman.  And I would like each of the men to play one time with each of the women (and vice versa), which should be possible given four rounds and four people of the opposite gender, and play one time against each of the women.  And where each man plays against two of the other three men one time, and against the third twice (because someone has to face each other at least twice).
I'm having trouble matching this up by hand.
Basically, I'd like three rounds of "gender" doubles that exhaust the possible combinations with gender.  And then four mixed doubles rounds that allow as much mixing of players as possible.
E.g., the three gender double rounds are:
(1,2) vs (3,4) and (5,6) vs (7,8);
(1,3) vs (2,4) and (5,7) vs (6,8);
(1,4) vs (2,3) and (5,8) vs (6,7).
It's the four mixed rounds that meet my criteria above that I can't figure out.

This seems to work: (1,5) vs (2,6) and (3,7) vs (4,8);
(1,6) vs (3,8) and (2,7) vs (4,5);
(1,7) vs (4,6) and (2,8) vs (3,5);
(1,8) vs (2,5) and (3,6) vs (4,7)

Thanks.  There are some issues with that.  E.g., player 1 plays player 6 twice; player 2 plays player 5 three times.  I would like it so that player 1 (male) plays against players 5-8 (female) exactly once each.

How did I missed that, I thought I checked carefully

I've worked on this enough (though not in a really systemic way) I almost wonder if it's not possible.  I haven't attempted a proof of that.

I found an error in my original post (other than overlooking a possibility as called out in the comments). It turns out my proof of impossibility was wrong. This tournament has all the desired properties (where I've relabelled the women as $a,b,c,d$ for clarity):
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\text{Round}&\text{North Court}&\text{South Court}\\\hline
1&1a\text{ vs }2b&3c\text{ vs }4d\\
2&1b\text{ vs }2c&3d\text{ vs }4a\\
3&1c\text{ vs }3a&2d\text{ vs }4b\\
4&1d\text{ vs }4c&2a\text{ vs }3b\end{array}$$

Thank you!  That's very helpful, including the notation change.  Question.  When you consider the case when the women also repeat (as well as the men) in the second round, don't you have to consider whether a and b might be paired with 3 and 4 (rather than 1 and 2)?  I think the proof carries through in any event, but is there a reason you would not have to consider it?  Thanks again!

@Howard - while rewriting the post to cover the case you pointed out, I discovered an error in my considerations of the cases I had covered. While the women repeating in the same round as the men still does not work when the additional cases are considered, I was wrong about the case when the women repeat in a different round than the men. I have changed the post to give a positive answer.

Thanks!  I’m not sure the proposed solution works though.  Each man does not play against each of the women (and similarly in the other direction). For example, man 1 does not playing against woman d.

@Howard - Dagnabbit! I think I got so caught up in making sure the men and women teamed up with everyone that I forgot to check on whether they also opposed everyone. $4$ and $d$ face off in three of the four rounds! I strongly suspect that the tournament is indeed impossible after all, but after so long I no longer remember the reasoning and do not have time right now to chase it down.
